# cosmosdb CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery ChangeFeedOption StartTime is not returning documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to fetch documents which are changed since last run. When I set ChangeFeed option StartTime I am not getting any rows. When  I set StartFromBeginning, I am getting documents.

```
IDocumentQuery<Document> query = client.CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery(
                 UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
                new ChangeFeedOptions
                {
                    StartFromBeginning = true,
                    PartitionKeyRangeId = partitionkeyRangeId,
                    RequestContinuation = token,
                    MaxItemCount = Batchsize,
                    // Set reading time: only show change feed results modified since StartTime
                    StartTime = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(365)

                });
```

var temp = query.ExecuteNextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: I can see one of the potential problems but i need more info. If you want documents changed since a specific time why do you provide a requestContinuation token?

Comment: In your sample code you are specifying both, `StartFromBeginning` and `StartTime`, also, what's the value of the `RequestContinuation`? I assume it's `null` for the first request?

Comment: RequestContinuation will help us in paging. MaxItemCount is my batchsize. If after given date if there are more documents than my batch size, RequestContinuation will help us in fetching in batches.

Comment: As per documentation, StartTime will override StartFromBeginning. Even when I tried without StartFromBeginning, I am not retrieving any documents.